# Why I'm not able to attach a tooltip to my textarea in CSS? (it works on hyperlinks though)

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bw5re2r/), I don't know why I can't attach the tooltip to my textarea... Is there any other way to make that nice-looking tooltip to any input field or textarea?

Here's my html file:

```
<div id="sth">
<a href="#" class="tooltip-top" data-tooltip="This is a tooltip.">Tooltip Top</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip-left" data-tooltip="This is a tooltip.">Tooltip Left</a><br>
<textarea class="tooltip-right" data-tooltip="This is a tooltip.">Where is the right tooltip? </textarea><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip-bottom" data-tooltip="This is a tooltip.">Tooltip Bottom</a>
    </div>
```

CSS content is in the fiddle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's not possible to use css :hover for textarea without anything else, but you can do this in preferably jQuery. There are many tooltip-plugins for jQuery.

https://www.google.se/search?q=css+textarea+hover&gws_rd=cr&ei=vNQ7VbafDoThywP574HoBw#q=jquery+tooltip